# How to load variables from file into windows environment variables in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following `Jenkinsfile`

```
node  {
    stage 'checkout'
    deleteDir()
    checkout scm

    load 'LoadTheseVariables.txt'  

    echo "MYKEY: ${MYKEY}"
    echo "REPO: ${REPO}"

    bat 'echo MYKEY is %MYKEY%'
    bat 'echo REPO is %REPO%'        
}
```

The file `LoadTheseVariables.txt` contains:

```
MYKEY="ThisIsTheKey"
REPO="ThisIsTheRepo"
```

The output of the Jenkins build is:

```
<..snip..>
[Pipeline] load
[Pipeline] { (LoadTheseVariables.txt)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // load
[Pipeline] echo
MYKEY: ThisIsTheKey
[Pipeline] echo
REPO: ThisIsTheRepo
[Pipeline] bat
[test] Running batch script

D:\Jenkins\workspace\test>echo MYKEY is  
MYKEY is 
[Pipeline] bat
[test] Running batch script

D:\Jenkins\workspace\test>echo REPO is  
REPO is 
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The Jenkins pipeline can see the variables but why can't my windows cmd environment see the variables? I even tried this step before the `bat` commands at the end: `bat 'refreshenv'` but that didn't reload the environment with those variables.

How can I load variables from a file in a Windows job and have them loaded into the environment at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use double quotes instead of single around the `bat` command. Seems to work fine.

Comment: what about if its external batch file